# WPF урезание текста через свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, property

Пытаюсь реализовать свойство для UserControl. Нужно что бы вводимы текст сокращался если он длиннее определённого количества символов. Не знаю может есть какие ни будь готовые свойства, но я их не нашел. Пробую задать например следующим образом.

```
    public string Named
    {
        get
        {
            string a = (string)GetValue(NamedProperty);
            if (a.Length > 18)
            {
                a = a.Remove(18) + "...";
            }
            return a; 
        }
        set
        {
            string a = value;
            if(a.Length >18)
            {
                a = a.Remove(18) + "...";
                SetValue(NamedProperty, a);
            }
            else SetValue(NamedProperty, value);

        }
    }
    public  static readonly DependencyProperty NamedProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Named), typeof(string), typeof(AccountListItem), new PropertyMetadata("Нет имени"));
```

Но это не работает. Как такое можно реализовать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно что бы вводимый текст сокращался

Значение свойства можно обрезать при выводе в UI, например, так:

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

А для определения длины текста можно использовать класс `FormattedText`.

```
var ft = new FormattedText(
               "0123456789",
               CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-ru"),
               FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
               new Typeface("Verdana"),
               32,
               Brushes.Black);
ft.Trimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
ft.MaxTextWidth = 30;
Console.WriteLine(ft.Width);
```

Comment: Ну у него явно вопрос о редактировании текста, а не просто в его отображении

Comment: @ixSci в вопросе сказано "нужно что бы вводимый текст сокращался" т.е. сокращать его надо при выводе, т.е. в контроле

Answer (score 1):

Хотя я не вижу всего Вашего кода, но в нём есть несколько проблем. Первая проблема находится в опубликованном Вами коде: `set/get` никогда не вызываются из XAML, когда речь идёт о `DependencyProperty`.Поэтому свойство должно выглядеть так и никогда не должно выглядеть иначе(**никакой логики в** `get/set`):

```
public string Named
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(NamedProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(NamedProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Далее, нам нужно как-то обрезать то, что нам `TextBox` «прислал». Для этого существует специальный обработчик, который можно задать при регистрации DP:

```
private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    var str = (string)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
    if(str.Length > 18)
    {
        str = str.Remove(18) + "...";
        var mainWindow = (MainWindow)dependencyObject;
        mainWindow.Named = str;
    }
}
```

Теперь код будет делать то, что Вам нужно. Но важно соблюдение ещё одного условия: мы должны заставить TextBox посылать новые данные на каждый введённый символ. Для этого существует свойство `UpdateSourceTrigger`. Вот как будет выглядеть наш `TextBox` в XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Named, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: _"`str.Length > 18`"_ -- если ширина окна или системные настройки шрифтов изменятся, то 18 символов могут не поместиться.

Comment: @Stack, безусловно. Но это уже на совести автора. Мой ответ покрывает лишь то, что спросил автор(по крайней мере как я понял, что ему нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так

```
private string _named;
public string Named
    {
        get
        {
            return _named;
        }
        set
        {

            else _named = value.Sustring(0,18);
            RaiseOfPropertyChanged(Named);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, что для этого нужно реализовывать специальный интерфейс. У автора DP в коде.